# Rails 5.0.0.1, ActiveRecord includes with select and has_many through

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using this lines of code to generate my table:

```
def index
  @documentation_languages = Documentation::Language
    .includes(:tags)
    .select(:id, :abbreviation, :name, :version)
    .order(:slug)
end
```

and they wil call:

```
SELECT "documentation_languages"."id", "documentation_languages"."abbreviation", "documentation_languages"."name", "documentation_languages"."version" FROM "documentation_languages" ORDER BY "documentation_languages"."slug" ASC
SELECT "documentation_language_tags".* FROM "documentation_language_tags" WHERE "documentation_language_tags"."language_id" IN (2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17)
SELECT "documentation_tags".* FROM "documentation_tags" WHERE "documentation_tags"."id" = 1
```

I am using `has_many :tags, through: :language_tags` inside `Documentation::Language` model. Is it any way I could select such as `documentation_tags.name` from the included `tags` table?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out by using the `scope` argument of `has_many` and change the code to:

```
has_many :tags, ->{ select(:name) }, through: :language_tags
```